# How will you design your classes with this requisites?

Tags: c#, xml, enums

Good afternoon;
Let us suppose we have an object called **element** with properties like this:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **name** | **type** | **description** |
| id | integer | element identifier |
| name | string | element name |
| origin | integer | element origin: 0 = natural 1 = artificial 2 = mix 3 = none 4 = gov |
| class | integer | element class: - **If origin = 0 then:** 0 = rainy 1 = sunny 2 = foggy 3 = cloudy 4 = none - **If origin = 1 OR origin = 4 then:** 0 = nonatural 1 = disaster |
| subclass | integer | element subclass: **If origin = 0 & class = 4 then:** 0 = investigate 1 = talk 2 = rest **If origin = 1 then:** 0 = good 1 = bad 2 = none **If source = 4 then:** 0 = countryA 1 = countryB 2 = countryC |

What I want is to traduce this into classes to be able to control the "changing values" of that enums(?)(took values from xml files):

And the class could be something like:

```cs
public int id { get; set; }
       
public string name { get; set; }
       
public ElementOrigin origin { get; set; }
     
public ElementClassIfOrigin0 class { get; set; }
     
public ElementClassIfOrigin1Or4 class2 { get; set; }


public enum ElementOrigin 
    {
        
        [XmlEnum("0")] natural,
        [XmlEnum("1")] artificial,
        [XmlEnum("2")] mix,
        [XmlEnum("3")] none,
        [XmlEnum("4")] gov
    }

    
    public enum ElementClassIfOrigin0 
    {
        
        [XmlEnum("0")] rainy,
        [XmlEnum("1")] sunny,
        [XmlEnum("2")] foggy,
        [XmlEnum("3")] cloudy
    }
    
    public enum ElementClassIfOrigin1Or4 
    {
        
        [XmlEnum("0")] nonatural,
        [XmlEnum("1")] disaster
    }
```

What I want if to develop a logic that can handle all possible scenarios, but as the enum can change a lot, like that table; what is the best way to prepare classes for its use within this scenario(polymorphism would be helpfull?)

Because what I was trying to avoid too is something like this:

```cs
case ElementOrigin.Natural
                        when element.classIfOrigin1== ClassIfOrigin0.natural:
                        break;

case ElementOrigin.Natural
                        when element.classIfOrigin1 == ClassIfOrigin0.artificial:
                        break;

case ElementOrigin.Natural
                        when element.classIfOrigin1 == ClassIfOrigin0.none:
                        break;
//and so on..
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Consider making an `Element` immutable, so that the last step of construction can validate its properties.  Perhaps use the builder pattern to make it easier to construct new `Element`s and/or start with an existing `Element` as a base for a new `Element`.

Comment: `class` and `subclass` are not `enums`, you could declare those values as constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `class` and `subclass` properties are merely numbers and don't need to be `enums` (as suggested by @rfmodulator in their comment), you could try this approach when creating your class:

```csharp
public class Element
{
    public Element(int id, string name, Origin origin) => (Id, Name, Origin) = (id, name, origin);

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Origin Origin { get; set; }
    
    public WeatherType? WeatherType { get; set; }
    public Classification? Classification { get; set; }
    public Reaction? Reaction { get; set; }
    public Rating? Rating { get; set; }
    public Country? Country { get; set; }

    public int? Class => Origin switch
    {
        Origin.Natural => (int?)WeatherType,
        Origin.Artificial => (int?)Classification,
        Origin.Gov => (int?)Classification,
        _ => null
    };

    public int? SubClass => Origin switch
    {
        Origin.Natural when Class == (int)WeatherType.None => (int?)Reaction,
        Origin.Artificial => (int?)Rating,
        Origin.Gov => (int?)Country,
        _ => null
    };
}

public enum Country
{
    CountryA = 0,
    CountryB = 1,
    CountryC = 2
}

public enum Rating
{
    Good = 0,
    Bad = 1,
    None = 2
}

public enum Reaction
{
    Investigate = 0,
    Talk = 1,
    Rest = 2
}

public enum Classification
{
    Nonnatural = 0,
    Disaster = 1
}

public enum WeatherType
{
    Rainy = 0,
    Sunny = 1,
    Foggy = 2,
    Cloudy = 3,
    None = 4
}

public enum Origin
{
    Natural = 0,
    Artificial = 1,
    Mix = 2,
    None = 3,
    Gov = 4
}
```

The properties `WeatherType`, `Classification`, `Reaction`, `Rating` and `Country` can then be conditionally displayed and toggled in a UI, which again will result in appropriate values for `Class` and `SubClass`.

If you also need to populate `Class` and `SubClass` on instantiation, you could add another constructor that populates the "base" properties:

```
public Element(int id, string name, Origin origin, int? classValue = null, int? subClassValue = null)
    : this(id, name, origin)
{
    switch (origin)
    {
        case Origin.Natural:
            WeatherType = (WeatherType?)classValue;
            if (classValue == (int)WeatherType.None)
            {
                Reaction = (Reaction?)subClassValue;
            }
            return;
        case Origin.Artificial:
            Classification = (Classification?)classValue;
            Rating = (Rating?)subClassValue;
            return;
        case Origin.Gov:
            Classification = (Classification?)classValue;
            Country = (Country?)subClassValue;
            return;
    }
}
```